# How to get the historical floor price data (minutes) of a specified NFT?

Tags: nft

**Through an NFT contract address and a timestamp in minutes, the historical floor price at that moment can be returned.**

This floor price is the floor price listed in the market (like the floor price displayed by gem.xyz), not the sale floor price.
For example, the function of nftscoring.com is very good, and you can also capture its api address for querying historical floor prices, but it can only display historical floor price data within 30 days, and it does not have 1-minute precision.

[image]

Many platforms have this function, but unfortunately, when querying historical floor prices for all time periods, the time interval for returning data is often hours or even days.

**I have been trying for a few days to solve this problem. Happy to be able to ask questions here. I hope you can give me some pointers on what I should do, thank you very much.**

Answer (score 0):

Gallop offers both off-chain and on-chain floor prices for sales and listings, and provides a variety of data and analytics APIs. The data available dates back several years and can be queried in one-hour intervals. Gallop's readme page allows users to test both APIs, including the sales OHLC and listing OHLC, with the candle's low representing the floor. For reference, here are the links:
https://gallop.readme.io/reference/getethcollectionsalesohlc-1 and https://gallop.readme.io/reference/getethcollectionlistingsohlc.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options like [Alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/getfloorprice), [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/nft-api), or [Moralis](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/nft-api) to get access to on-chain data such as information around a particular NFT token or a collection or even floor prices!

I think you have to figure out which one solves your problem better while giving you the best performance.